# Powershell returning results only if using parameter instead of using select

Tags: powershell

I have an odd issue where results are returned only if I use a parameter. When I try using select, it returns the correct number of rows but without any data.

This works but gives me **all** data from a group of json files when I only need a few fields:

```
$json =
Get-ChildItem -File $filePath -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime] $filesNewerThan -and $_.FullName -match "SITE ADD" } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json} #| Format-Table -autosize 

$json
```

This code doesn't return any data

```
$json =
Get-ChildItem -File $filePath -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime] $filesNewerThan -and $_.FullName -match "SITE ADD" } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json} #| Format-Table -autosize 

$json | Select lastName, zipCode, birthdate, Address, data
```

Anything I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are multiple input files and that each input file contains JSON *arrays*:

Up to PowerShell v6.x, `ConvertFrom-Json` infamously sends arrays *as a whole* through the pipeline instead of *enumerating* their elements - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424).

In your case, you'll end up with an *array of arrays*, so `Select-Object lastName, ...` tries to access properties `.lastName, ...` on each element *array*, where no such property is found.

You can force enumeration of each array element by simply piping to `Write-Output`:

```
$json | Write-Output | Select-Object lastName, zipCode, birthdate, Address, data
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @jdids; my pleasure.